# How to get the substring after a given string

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and struggle with string parsing. I have a string like this:

```
C:\User\Max\Pictures\
```

And I got multiple file paths:

```
C:\User\Max\Pictures\car.jpg
C:\User\Max\Pictures\trains\train.jpg
```

How can I strip the base path from those file paths to get:

```
car.jpg
trains\train.jpg
```

Something like this failed:

```
string path = "C:\\User\\Max\\Pictures\\";
string file = "C:\\User\\Max\\Pictures\\trains\\train.jpg";

string newfile = file.Substring(file.IndexOf(path));
```

Comment: `IndexOf` returns the _starting_ position of path in the string, in this case 0, that's why you need to use something different ;>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to get the substring of `file` after the *length* of `path`:

```
string newfile = file.Substring(path.Length);
```

Note that it's a good idea to use `Path` methods like [`Path.GetFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename) when dealing with file paths (though it's not good applyable to the "train" example).

Comment: That's what I wanted, thanks. I was not able to use the Path class because of the train example.

Comment: IMO `String.SubString` is better than `String.Replace` in OP's cases.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer would be to replace your path with an empty string :

```
string filePath = file.Replace(path, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are special classes to handle filepaths

```
var filePath = new FileInfo("dd");
```

In filePath.Name is the filename of the file whitout directory

So for your scenario you want to strip base dir. So you can do this

```
var filePath = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\train\test.xml");
var dir = filePath.FullName.Replace(@"c:\temp", String.Empty);
```